# Application crashes with Theme.Dialog

Tags: android

I'm new to Android dev and so follow some tutorials to get familiar with it. In the latest I try to apply the `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` to my activity, but my application crashes at launch time.

I also try with `@style/Theme.AppCombat` and I get the following error:

> no resource found that matches that given name

There is my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activity101"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCombat" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity101"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "When I do that, the application crashes" -- use LogCat to figure out where you are crashing and why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this "when I try the "@style/Theme.AppCombat" I still get an error of "no resource found that matches that given name"" -- did you write such a theme? Android does not have an `AppCombat` theme. If you use the `appcompat-v7` piece of the Android Support package, there is an `AppCompat` theme (note the `p` in place of the `b`).

Comment: Mate thanks alot, that actually helped. Did not notice the p instead of the b..Ought to be more cautious next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in test this way:
open AndroidManifest.xml file and in Application tab then in Application Attributes section select your favorite  theme for your project(after select browse button in dialog box select system resources and write theme and after select your theme) and finally save your file.